# XCode Auto Layout behaving badly

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

In order to get an iPhone layout to display at 'correct' dimensions on iPad, I'm putting everything (rose) into a view (blue) within the ViewController (gold)

[Click / tap to see Schematic View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPEu3.png)

The iPad is shown as the larger frame with the grey status bar.

So to cater for 7plus size iPhones downwards, I'd have to set up constraints for the 7+ within an iPad frame with different priorities
in different directions. Once the blue view is set, i should happily be able to add my Sub Views in I.B.

Since the whole lot has to appear in the very centre of Ipads, step (1) is to set alignment centre-line constraints of the blue View with priority of 1000.

Next would be to fix the size for iPad displays larger then 7+. Acheived with setting size constraints as a maximum to shrink from. I've only shown the ≤680, so that height or less as in step (2) but a lesser priority, say 750.

Then for it to reduce down in size toward SE size i want to hold that say 20 points away from the viewController (gold). So the constraint for that should be ≥20. as shown at (3), I've assigned 740

The principal works nicely in the horizontal direction, but not the vertical. I've tried endlessly to adjust different priority assignments, including the 'Content Hugging' and 'Content Compression Resistance'properties and I never seem to get the desired results once I put the actual entities I want to see (rose) within the Blue view.

I've read Apple's Autolayout Design Guides closely enough to almost say I've written them, and after 35+years of CAD and 3D animation modelling, I think I could describe objects in text parameters before the iPhone existed.

But I've been bested here. Am I taking the long way 'round to just get an ** iPhone only ** layout to display correctly? My little bald spot thanks you for your answer.

Comment: Just realized the circled (1) is in the wrong position. Consider it near a centre-line

Comment: It's very hard to imagine what have done...what you want...and what code/constraints you have written. Show us the end result you got from Simulator. Also show us the constraints you wrote. Don't write about it, literally show us what you did!

Comment: Is your goal to have an "iPhone Only Portrait Only" app design? And you just want it to "scale up" when running on iPads?

Comment: @DonMag, Yes, an iPhone Poitrait only, but I don't want it to "scale up" on an iPad. According Apple's rejection note: " ...app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad" so from that: the scaling has to stop at the 7+.

Comment: @Honey, I'll try to add that as an edit later today

Comment: @bananamiss - you *may* be over-thinking this... here are screen-caps of a similar layout... UIView with padding on each side, containing a couple labels... Very, very basic constraints - default priorities, no vary fro traits, etc.  Caps are from various simulator devices (scaled): https://imgur.com/a/a5G7D

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use trait variations instead of trying to handle layout for every size class in one set of constraints. I think if you take that approach, you can accomplish what you're after with a lot less work and in a way that's independent of devices that may appear in the future.

Also, keep in mind that if your app supports iPad multitasking, you may have sizes on an iPad that you're not expecting (like iPhone portrait width in device landscape orientation).

With autolayout, try not to think in terms of device type or orientation. Think in terms of the appearance you want for a particular size class, wherever it appears, in whatever device orientation. That gives you the opportunity to create a the best user experience for a given display area, and will make your life easier during initial development as well as when new features are added or new user devices are in the mix.